# twitter tweet media entities retrieving [object object ] node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter

i'm retrieving tweet data but i want to look at the media entities. i'm getting media link but when i try to get **media entities** i'm getting [object object ] in console.

what i'm trying to archive here is i want to look at the media entities whether its contain image or video. it that possible in node.js ?

[image]

Comment: It's always a good idea to include relevant code so we can help reproduce and troubleshoot the issue. See [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you want to see your result use `console.log(JSON.stringify(your_object))`

Comment: thx mate. JSON.stringify solved my problem. it become bit tricky but it helped....